# Wrapping an atomic type and ensuring that it remains atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, thread-safety

I have a somewhat unique and interesting (and terrible) scenario that is forcing me to do some tricky stuff. The problem is as follows:

1. We need an atomic type to do lock-free synchronization between a realtime thread and a background loading thread.
2. The type (unfortunately) must compile on:

   a. QNX which only has c++03, but supports `boost::atomic`.

   b. Nucleus which has c++11 but cannot build `boost::atomic`

This is forcing me to consider using both `boost::atomic` and `std::atomic`. The way I am approaching this, is to generate a new type, that forwards all of the functionality to the relevant `atomic` type on the platform. The idea is something like this:

---

**Atomic.hpp**

```
namespace osal { namespace detail {

template <typename T, template <class> class TAtomic >
struct AtomicImpl {

    void store(T desired, memory_order order = osal::memory_order_seq_cst) 
    {
        _atomic.store(desired, order);
    }

    // ... Other api

private:

    AtomicImpl& operator=(const AtomicImpl& rhs);
    // ... Other blocked operations
    TAtomic<T> _atomic;
};

}}


#if defined QNX
    #include <osal/QNX/Atomic.hpp>
#elif defined NUCLEUS
    #include <osal/NUCLEUS/Atomic.hpp>
#endif
```

This lays out a class which will forward to the `atomic` type with the correct API. Luckily the `boost` and `std` implementation match almost exactly.

---

Then in each of the individual OS files, something like this:

**Nucleus/Atomic.hpp**

```
#include <atomic>

namespace osal 
{ 

template <typename T> struct atomic
   {
      typedef detail::AtomicImpl<T, std::atomic> type;
   };
}
```

This creates the atomic type with `std::atomic` allowing to use like:

```
osal::atomic<uint8_t>::type a;
a.store(1);
```

---

In order to deal with the concept of memory order, there exists a similar system with a file to delegate to each of the OS implementations using the preprocessor. In the implementation, for eg. Nucleus, we have this:

**Nucleus/MemoryOrder.hpp**

```
#include <memory>
namespace osal {

using std::memory_order;
using std::memory_order_relaxed;
...
}
```

Obviously the equivalent `using boost::...` will be in the QNX file (lucky that they match again!).

### The question

This appears to work. I can make an atomic and do operations on it. I have a concern:

*Is this still atomic?*

Now that we have introduced an indirection in the API, could there be problems with the order of the calls to the atomic object?

As a bonus question, given the constraints, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: w.r.t. atomic (not so much memoryorder) you can look at the generated code, see if it is in fact atomic.  (Perhaps use the most restrictive memoryorder when doing this.

Comment: The libraries don't get to leverage any compiler magic in the API itself, so as long as your API is identical to the types used in both libraries, I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Adding a function call layer should do nothing in regards to atomicity.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I thought so, I also thought even if the outlying op is not atomic, it won't matter because the inner calls are. But i wanted to check.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: It seems easier to do this in assembler than subject yourself to this pain. The threadsafety would be obvious based on the instructions.

Comment: In similar scenario, we used namespace alias. So you have `namespace actomics = std` on one platform and `namespace actomics = boost` on other.

Comment: @user14717 I don't think writing assembly code would be easier than using `std::atomic` ...

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev Good suggestion, but won't this also pull in all of `std`? I just want this atomic type in the `osal` namespace.

Comment: Sure it will. On the other hand, it is less effort than maintaining own wrapper. I can also think of intermediate solution, like defining wrapper for atomic that is publicly inherit from std::atomic or boost::atomic. I'm pretty sure you solution is safe, but it looks too verbose.

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev Inheriting from the `std::atomic` is not a good idea, it will not have a virtual destructor which could cause very bad things to happen if people use it as a `std` type pointer. I think wrapping the API is not that bad, and it gives us a bit of flexibility.

Comment: There is also Intel TBB atomics: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506277

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks for the suggestion. I think the chances of this compiling on nucleus are small though :(

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Overlooked your OSes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> Nucleus which has c++11 but cannot build `boost::atomic`

`boost::atomic<T>` type is header-only, you can use it without having to build `boost::atomic` library.

You can use `boost::atomic<T>` directly and unconditionally on both platforms (provided your platforms are supported).

There are a few bits of `boost::atomic` library that require building, see `src` and `test` directories in https://github.com/boostorg/atomic, however, using `boost::atomic<T>` doesn't require those.

Comment: Is this a suggestion for a different way to do it? Can you clarify this? It is not super clear if this is an answer or not.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Just use `boost::atomic<T>`.

Comment: So there is a team of Nucleus guys that when i say why doesn't this work, they say *it just doesn't, so use `std::atomic`*. I am not sure what it is about `boost::atomic` but we can't build or run the unit test suite. We therefore cannot check if it is actually functional.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I would try getting technical answers from that team.